# How can I check for a second degree equation fit for a dataset?

Tags: r

Using the dataset "iris" as an example.

Assuming I'm trying to figure out if there's a model that is a fit for the variables "Sepal.Width" and "Sepal.Length", if I were to check for a linear regression model I could simply use the `lm` function:

```
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

Let's assume that my R-squared value is low, and I instead have a hunch that instead of a linear model, it could be a second degree model instead. So something like this:

```
Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Width^2
```

Is there any command/packages in R that would help me identify whether my data is more likely to follow a second degree equation fit?

Comment: You can always run the regression with the second order variable and check its significance and joint significance, but really you should let theory guide your analysis, not the data.

Comment: @trijamms: How would you determine whether theory says a hyperbola might be a better fit?

Comment: @Woels Depends on what you're studying. If you're not familiar with the theoretical underpinnings already, check the literature. Maybe dust off an old text book. What is the relationship you're looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of the formula interface would not allow this formula to mean what you think it should mean. You would need to do this:

```
Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + I(Sepal.Width)^2
```

But even that would not be the correct method to use for statistical inference. Rather you would compare these two models:

```
  mod1 <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)

  mod2 <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ poly( Sepal.Width, 2) , data=iris)

anova( mod1, mod2)
```

The `poly` function creates orthogonal polynomials and the inferential statistics can properly account for the correlations between X and X^2. The results:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width
Model 2: Sepal.Length ~ poly(Sepal.Width, 2)
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)  
1    148 100.756                             
2    147  98.752  1    2.0044 2.9838 0.0862 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

... shows a suggestive p-value of 0.086, but many journals would find this uninteresting. Other than the coding issue this might be better handled at CrossValidated.com to which I would refer any follow-up questions.